# discord.py Get channel permissions and use them in a different channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to copy the permissions of a channel and then use them in a different guild

```
@bot.command() #get channel permissions
async def copychannel(ctx):
    chan_perm = ctx.channel.overwrites
    print(chan_perm)
```

output:

```
{<Role id=926970474183925870 name='@everyone'>: <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at 0x00000291FC3AB940>}
#it is a dict
```

```
@bot.command() #trying to use these permissions on a different guild
async def channel(ctx):
    c={"<Role id=923673221469966336 name='@everyone'>": "<discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at 0x00000291FC3AB940>"}
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name='test', overwrites=c)
```

output:

```
#It is giving me an error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: Expected PermissionOverwrite received str
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: in which line there is an error?

Comment: @OrangoMango
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name='test', overwrites=c)

Comment: Are you running these commands in two different executions? i.e. Running the first command, collecting the output, then pasting that into the code for your second command and running that? Also, why are you trying to copy permissions in a guild that has different `Role` objects to another guild? That will fail since the roles in one guild do not exist in another guild.

Comment: @metro yes I am doing it in two different executions. With a different command I'll also copy the roles so that they exist in both the guilds. Btw in this case it is the everyone role which is in every server and I just changed the role id which is different

Comment: The problem is that you can't just copy the string representation of a `PermissionOverwrite` (or a `Role` for that matter) and use that in your code. The `PermissionOverwrite` represents an object, which is effectively deleted once you terminate execution of the script. You should store the returned overwrites `dict` in a variable and use it in your call to `create_text_channel()` in the same script execution.

Comment: @metro Hey thank you for the help. The bot successfully created a channel but the permissions aren't correct because, as you said before, it will fail since the roles in one guild do not exist in another guild. The everyone role is in both the servers but the role id is different. How can I edit the role id in the PermissionOverwrite?

Comment: @iksskjj The `PermissionOverwrite` itself does not contain a role id; rather, it is mapped to one via a `dict`. If you have a `dict` with `Role` objects as keys (this is what is returned by `GuildChannel.overwrites`, you probably want to get the @everyone `Role` object from the new guild (through `Guild.roles`), and create a new `dict` with that object as the key and the `PermissionOverwrite` object as the value (assuming you only want to transfer permissions for the everyone role).

Comment: The answer below effectively does what I explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A revised form of [Konstantinos Georgiadis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13842502/konstantinos-georgiadis) answer to clear up confusion about where code goes:

First, we need to actually obtain the overwrites from the original server. To do this:

```
@bot.command() # command to use in the first server to copy channel permissions
async def copy(ctx):
    global overwrites
    overwrites = ctx.channel.overwrites
```

Now, we can use those overwrites to "paste" our permissions into the new server:

```
@bot.command() # command to paste ...
async def paste(ctx):
    for role, overwrite in overwrites.items():    # this is the dict of overwrites from copy()
        if type(role) is discord.Role:   # we are assuming role is a Role, but could be a Member
            new_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role.name)
            modified_overwrites[role] = overwrite
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="channel", overwrites=modified_overwrites)
```

Effectively, this iterates through all of the permission overwrites from our "template". For each overwrite, it matches the role in the old server to the corresponding role in the new server, so that we don't get any errors when creating the channel. Then, it creates the channel with our new set of overwrites and roles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
overwrites = {}
for key, value in ctx.channel.overwrites.items():
    role = get(guild.roles, name=key.name)
    overwrites[role] = value
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="name", overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: I assume that `get()` referenced here is referring to `discord.utils.get()` since that would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, i mean get from `discord.utils.get`

Comment: Hey @KonstantinosGeorgiadis thank for all your help but this command only works if I want to clone a channel in the same server. Down below there's the new code I tried, which is not working.